# how to solve $\log (x+1) +3 = \frac{2}{x+2}$

Tags: logarithms

From the Jan 17 NYS Algebra 2 Regents, a multiple choice question with seemingly no satisfying answer:

"When $g(x) = \frac{2}{x+2}$ and $h(x) = \log (x+1)+3$ are graphed on the same set of axes, which coordinates best approximate their point of intersection?"

$$(1) \ (-0.9, 1.8)$$
$$(2) \ (-0.9, 1.9)$$
$$(3) \ (1.4, 3.3)$$
$$(4) \ (1.4, 3.4)$$

Plugging in an $x$ value of $-0.9$ yields $y$ values of $1.8181$... and $2$, respectively, so neither answers # 1 nor # 2 are 'best,' and an $x$-value of $1.4$ does not work at all for $g(x)$.

On Desmos I obtained an approximation of $(-.927, 1.8638)$ as the intersection of the graphs, i.e., approximately the 'solution.'

Here's my real question: can this type of equation, $\frac{2}{x+2} = \log(x+1)+3$ actually be solved algebraically; and if so, how?

Many thanks, as always.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the "Lambert W Function" for reference.

Comment: Only hope is numeric. "Lambert W Function"  will not help you in any way.

Comment: Can't see a closed form solution but consider $log(x+1)-\dfrac{2}{x+2}+3 = 0$ and apply newtons method to find $x$